# jaxb xsd prefix package names

Tags: java, xsd, jaxb

I have a large xsd file (with imports), which can only be generated when the xjc compiler gets to pick package names based on the target attributes specified inside each of the xsd files. If I specify a specific package name, then it tries to place all generated content in that one package and I get a ton of name collisions.

The issue is with the package names. I would like to prefix these package names.
Ideally I'd like com.othercompany.spec._2.Error to become com.mycompany.productx.data.spec.Error instead.
But I can live with com.mycompany.productx.data.com.othercompany.spec._2.Error

The latter would only require "com.mycompany.productx.data." to be prefixed to all the generated package names.

Is this possible at all?

Alternatively, I could take the xjc generated output, and have Eclipse move the java files into the other package, but that's a manual step and I'd like an automated build process to handle it, so that when someone else has to regenerate it 6 months down the line, they don't have to think about this.

Answer (score 0):

To get a distinct package name per XML schema, you could generate classes from the XML schemas separately by leverage the episode file extension in XJC.

**Generate Java Classes from a.xsd to package `com.example.a`**

```
xjc -d out -p com.example.a -episode a.episode a.xsd
```

**Generate Java Classes from b.xsd (that imports a.xsd) to package `com.example.b`**

```
xjc -d out -p com.example.b b.xsd -extension -b a.episode
```

**For More Information**

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/12/reusing-generated-jaxb-classes.html

Comment: The -p com.example.b specifies a package name where all the generated content goes. This causes numerous of naming conflicts.

Comment: @Mike - My assumption was that the package name was causing the numerous naming conflicts when you called xjc on the root schema.  The approach I'm suggesting is that you start with the leaf schemas, and compile each with a different package name.  Then you compile the schemas that import the leaf schemas leveraging the generated episode files.