# JAXB - How can I apply a package prefix to all xsds

Tags: java, xsd, jaxb, prefix

The project I am attempting to work on uses multiple versions of an XSD schema, that includes hundreds of other XSD files to form that complete object.

I currently have JAXB generating the code for all of the xsd files using some custom bindings to remove duplicates, however when the same class file is generated for one of the newer versions it overwrites the original one.

I need to prefix all of the generated classes with a version package prefix.

This question asked the same thing and it did not get resolved.
[jaxb xsd prefix package names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8841615/jaxb-xsd-prefix-package-names)

Example project layout:

```
Version1\test.xsd-----------------------------(package foo)
Version1\externalXSDv1\external.xsd---(package bar)
Version2\test.xsd-----------------------------(package foo)
Version2\externalXSDv2\external.xsd---(package bar)
```

The xsd files contain the same namespace and most of the classes are the same.

I need to prefix all of the version1 generated classes with 'version1.foo' and 'version1.bar' while the version 2 generated classes would show as 'version2.foo' and 'version2.bar'

Any ideas how to do this?

jaxb:schemaBindings doesn't work unless I specify each xsd file and -p puts all of the classes in the same package, which strips away all of the original package.

Comment: You could just run the command 4 times from each directory with the package name argument?

Comment: I've tried that. The problem that results from that is that there are at least 100 xsd files that are contained in the schemas that I have to generate.   I've tried episode files to some success, but the various xsd files all reference each other in different packages, which results in duplicate classes getting generated all over the place

Comment: Have you tried using external `<bindings>` ?

Comment: I use bindings extensively, however I would have to rebind at least 100 (303 to be exact) target packages individually.

Comment: @Mciccarone I guess that following [LINK](https://jaxb.java.net/guide/Customizing_Java_packages.html) could be usefull if you want define a different package for all XSDs.

Comment: Such a good question. Pity it is not answered